# Does WP REST API have a built in route for calling menu?

Tags: menus, rest-api

Upon my research the latest [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209381/get-wp-navigation-menu-from-rest-api-v2) I was able to reference referred to the WP REST API plugin before it was built into core.  The best answer on the question referred to building a `custom endpoint` (I'm not a fan of using the plugin):

```
function get_menu() {
    # Change 'menu' to your own navigation slug.
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu');
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'myroutes', '/menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_menu',
    ) );
} );
```

I was unable to see anything mentioned in the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).  When reviewing all the `routes` in Postman I see everything but `menus`:

[image]

Is there a way in WP REST API that is built into core to get the `menu` without building a custom endpoint?  Am I missing it somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

> Does WP REST API have a built in route for calling menu?

Nope, the *menu* route is not currently (4.9.7) built-in, but there's a ticket for it in [#40878](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40878).

It's not mentioned on [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/08/23/rest-api-roadmap/) REST API roadmap though.